# Not sure if this is correct or not: "the ability to be able to"

Tags: differences, infinitives, present-participles

The sentence:

> Problems are an inevitable part of life, and one could argue that
>   happiness is not the absence of problems, but rather the ability **to be
>   able** to deal with them.

Is it **to be able** or **being able**?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the "ability to be able to deal with something" and the "ability to deal with something"? Can I have one without the other?

Comment: @PeterShor What about "Having the ability to deal with them"?

Comment: There are lots of ways to reword your sentence so as to get rid of the awkward and redundant *"ability to be able to"*, and that one's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The ability to be able" is still a bit redundant, right? How about these examples?

> "Happiness is not the absence of problems, but rather" being able to deal with them.

Or,

> "Happiness is not the absence of problems, but rather" having the ability to deal with them.

Either of these examples is grammatically correct and avoids the redundancy.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have submitted the full sentence in an edit above, hope that clarifies it up a bit.

Comment: Excellent. I have edited my answer accordingly. I hope it helps. :-)